# XML parsing: Document parsing required too much memory when set up using transactional replica to migrate data from on premise DB to Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, sqltalk

During the transactional replica set up from on premise DB to Azure. We hit XML parsing: Document parsing required too much memory when bcp data from a table.

Comment: Instead of using Replication can you consider using SQL Data Sync. XML is fully supported by SQL Data Sync. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

Comment: Hi Alberto, wondering whether this support sync the data from on premise DB to azure, instead of azure -> on premise DB.

Comment: It supports both. The hub database must be a an Azure Database and member databases must be an on-premise database or another Azure SQL Database. Since it syncs bi-directional y the data changes on on-premise database then it will be send to the hub database.